# does expo eas credential needs keystorePath in .jks or .keystore format

Tags: react-native, expo

## here is my credential.json file

> {
> "android": {
> "keystore": {
> "keystorePath": "./patent.jks",
> "keystorePassword": "oritipatents",
> "keyAlias": "oritipatentsAlias",
> "keyPassword": "oritipatents"
> }
> },
> "ios": {
>
> ```
> }
> ```
>
> }

@ every time i try generate the apk and try to install it gives me package coflick error